# Say if the following function is nulhomotopic

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, retraction

$f:\mathbb{R}^2 -\{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2 -\{0\} $ such that $f(x,y)=(x^2, y)$

I believe  this isn't nulhomotopic since I can't pass through 0, but I don't know how to justify this.
I think I should solve this using that composition of a nulhomotopic function with an arbitrary function is nulhomotopic, but still don't know how to apply this.

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The image is the right half plane, minus the origin surely?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see yet what does that mean?

Comment: Isn't the image a contractible set?

Comment: Oh you're right, because it's convex! Thank you very much!